# php remove duplicate returns

Tags: php, mysql

Hi in my app I have one content and media it has one to may relation. For example Titanic is the content and Youtube and WAP is the Media, now if content has two media present then it returns twice how can i remove the duplicate but keep the media with comma separated? like (YouTube, WAP)

here is my code:

```
 ->select('DISTINCT(c.id) as id, c.title, c.sequence, c.sequence_count, c.category_sequence, c.unique_id, c.priority, c.status')
        ->addSelect('o.slug as owner')
        ->addSelect('cat.slug as category')
        ->addSelect('m.name as media')
        ->innerJoin('c.content_owner', 'o')
        ->innerJoin('c.category', 'cat')
        ->leftJoin('c.media', 'm')
       // ->groupBy('c.title')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();

  if (isset($contents['media'])) {

        $media[] = $contents['media'];
        foreach ($contents as &$content) {

            $content['media'] = implode('/',array_unique($media));


        }
    }
```

I tried with this but is not working. it always return twice, Any help?

Comment: You did a lot of leftJoin. Could there be duplicated results in those joinned tables?

Comment: Which variable do you want to use at the end? What is the wanted output?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
->addSelect("GROUP_CONCAT(m.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS media")
...
...
->groupBy('c.id')
```